# R ggplot2: adding custom text to legend and value counts on sides of the heat map

Tags: ggplot2, heatmap

My input data looks like:

```
COMPANY      DOMAIN    REVIEW    PROGRESS
Company A    Service   Good      +
Company A    Response  Good      +
Company A    Delay     Very Good    
Company A    Cost      Poor      -
Company B    Service   Poor      -
Company B    Delay     Average  
Company B    Cost      Good      +
Company C    Service   Very Poor +
Company C    Cost      Average
```

I produced a heat map in which I add some text (value of the "PROGRESS" variable - i.e. plus or minus sign).[image: heatmap produced]

Here is my code:

```
require("ggplot2")

graph <- read.table("input.tab", header=T, sep="\t")

ggplot(data=graph, aes(x=COMPANY, y=DOMAIN, group=REVIEW, fill=REVIEW)) + 

geom_tile() + 

geom_text(aes(x=COMPANY, y=DOMAIN, label=PROGRESS)) + 

scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 

scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +

geom_vline(xintercept=seq(1.5, length(graph$COMPANY)+0.5)) + 
geom_hline(yintercept=seq(1.5, length(graph$DOMAIN)+0.5)) + 

theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    axis.title=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, size=12, hjust=1)
    )
```

However I am struggling adding (see figure modified manually below):

(1) the following "PROGRESS" legend as part of the color code already listed:

```
+   Better
-   Worse
```

(2) the count of data available on each row between the right side of the plot and the legend

(3) the count of data available on each column on top of the plot

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my proposed solution, I added comments in the code for you to understand what I did. There is probably a better way of generating the grid, though. Hope it helps.

```
graph <- read_csv(
"COMPANY      ,DOMAIN    ,REVIEW    ,PROGRESS
Company A    ,Service   ,Good      ,+
Company A    ,Response  ,Good      ,+
Company A    ,Delay     ,Very Good ,   
Company A    ,Cost      ,Poor      ,-
Company B    ,Service   ,Poor      ,-
Company B    ,Delay     ,Average  ,
Company B    ,Cost      ,Good      ,+
Company C    ,Service   ,Very Poor ,+
Company C    ,Cost      ,Average  ,")


ggplot() + 
  # moved aesthetics and data to each geom, 
  # if you keep them in the ggplot call,
  # you have to specify `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the rest of the geoms     
  geom_tile(data = graph,
            aes(x    = COMPANY, 
                y    = DOMAIN, 
                fill = REVIEW)) + 
  # changed from `geom_text` to `geom_point` with custom shapes
  geom_point(data = graph,
             aes(x     = COMPANY, 
                 y     = DOMAIN, 
                 shape = factor(PROGRESS, labels = c("Worse", "Better"))),
             size = 3) +
  # custom shape scale
  scale_shape_manual(name = "", values = c("-", "+")) +
  # calculate marginal totals "on the fly"
  # top total
  geom_text(data  = summarize(group_by(graph, COMPANY),
                              av_data  = length(!is.na(PROGRESS))),
            aes(x = COMPANY,
                y = length(unique(graph$DOMAIN)) + 0.7,
                label = av_data)) + 
  # right total
  geom_text(data  = summarize(group_by(graph, DOMAIN),
                              av_data  = length(!is.na(PROGRESS))),  
            aes(x = length(unique(graph$COMPANY)) + 0.7, 
                y = DOMAIN, label = av_data)) + 
  # expand the plotting area to accomodate for the marginal totals
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0.8)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0.8)) +
  # changed to `geom_segment` to generate the grid, otherwise grid extends
  # beyond the heatmap 
  # horizontal lines
  geom_segment(aes(y    = rep(0.5, 1 + length(unique(graph$COMPANY))),
                   yend = rep(length(unique(graph$DOMAIN)) + 0.5,
                              1 + length(unique(graph$COMPANY))),
                   x    = seq(0.5, 1 + length(unique(graph$COMPANY))),
                   xend = seq(0.5, 1 + length(unique(graph$COMPANY))))) + 
  # vertical lines
  geom_segment(aes(x    = rep(0.5, 1 + length(unique(graph$DOMAIN))),
                   xend = rep(length(unique(graph$COMPANY)) + 0.5, 
                              1 + length(unique(graph$DOMAIN))),
                   y    = seq(0.5, 1 + length(unique(graph$DOMAIN))),
                   yend = seq(0.5, 1 + length(unique(graph$DOMAIN))))) + 

  # custom legend order
  guides(fill  = guide_legend(order = 1), 
         shape = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  # theme tweaks
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.line        = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks       = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    plot.background  = element_blank(),
    axis.title       = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                               size  = 12,
                               hjust =  1,
                               # move text up 20 pt
                               margin = margin(-20,0,0,0, "pt")),
    # move text right 20 pt
    axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(0,-20,0,0, "pt"))
  )
```

[image: final_plot]